# How to return specific object attributes in spring boot queries with DAO?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, dao

in my Spring Boot application I have an entity called Person.class, which contains

```
long id;
String email;
String name;
String surname;
String address;
```

In the DAO class, I have a method:

```
List<Person> findAllByEmail(String email);
```

Which queries the Database and returns a list of Person.

I would like to return a list of Person with just some attributes, for example:

```
long id;
String email;
```

Without return the entire object.

This would be equivalent to execute the query:

```
"select id, email from person where email = ?"
```

But I would like to maintain the function query into the DAO as

```
List<Person> findAllByEmail(String email);
```

Without writing the queries by hand.

How can I do it ?

Comment: I am not sure how this is relevant, if you are using it within the code then doesn't matter. But if you want to return it to front end, then you must never use Model classes directly. Refer [this Entity to DTO conversion](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct) for reference.

Comment: You can just simple call for your required fields of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JPA Projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

1. Create interface with getters of desired columns

```java
interface WithIdAndEmail {
   long getId();
   String getEmail();
}
```

2. Use that interface as the return type of the method

```java
List<WithIdAndEmail> findAllByEmail(String email);
```

Comment: Okay, thank you! Where do I add the interface ? Into the class Person?

Comment: @user3476509 wherever you want. I would prefer placing it near relevant Repository classes

Comment: I got the error:  Could not write JSON: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [long]

Comment: @user3476509 try to use `Long` instead of `long`. Though I don't get why it's even being converted in JSON

Comment: @user3476509 if it's solved you can Accept my answer

Answer (score 2):

Returning multiple values from a method is not possible. In your calling method, when iterating over the returned `List<Person>`, you should read the required fields from each `Person` out of the `List` into local variables and work with those.

Comment: I would like to return the object Person, but with just the attributes id and email.

Comment: If you handle an instance of ```Person``` it always has all of the fields. Whether these fields actually contain useful information is another matter. But you cannot strip fields from a class. See Nikolai's answer for an approach using a different structure.